# How to know if a Google Places Add request did not pass the moderation?

Tags: google-places-api

I request Google Places API once a week to see if my requests to add new places have passed the moderation queue (if the scope has changed to google).

The problem is that I don't know how to know if a request has been rejected by the moderation.

The only solution seems to ask for get-current-place (or other "search" request) and look for the place, since the place must not appear in the result once rejected by the moderation, but I'm not really convinced by that solution.

Thanks

Comment: The [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a good or stable way to do this at the moment. Looking at search results gives an approximation, but there are other reasons that a valid place may not appear in the results, so it won't give a strong confirmation.